# Why is it not deleting data from mongoDB but still its showing success Message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Click event

this the click evet-handler for below HTML button

```
const deleteProduct = (productsId) =>{
        axios.delete(`/api/product/`,{
            params: {productsId}
        })
        .then(response =>{
            setSuccessMessage("Item Deleted Successfully", response, products)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            setErrorMessage("Item Deleting Failed")
        })
    }
```

HTML

the above click event comes here for the delete button

```
<div className="row justify-content-center">
                {products && products.map(p => (
                    <Card style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '50px 50px'}} key={p._id} value={p._id}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={p.imageLink} style={{width:'auto', height:'180px', objectFit:'cover'}}/>
                    <Card.Body >
                        <Card.Title>Name : {p.productName}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>Description : {p.productDesc}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text>Price : ${p.productPrice}</Card.Text>
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <Button className="mr-2" target="_blank"><FaPen /> Edit </Button>
                        <Button target="_blank" onClick={() => deleteProduct(p._id)}><FaTrash /> Delete </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                ))}
        </div>
```

Controller

this is delete controller for server side

```
exports.deleteAll = (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.query;
 Product.findByIdAndDelete(id , (error, data)=>{
     if(error) {
         console.log('error in deleting')
         throw error;
     }
     else{
         console.log('user has been deleted', data);
         res.status(204).json(data)
     }
 })
```

}

Route

router for delete

```
router.delete('/',authenticateJWT, productController.deleteAll)
```

it is showing
DELETE /api/product/?productsId=600c1e6a48d6c4422c095f03 204 4.412 ms - -

but data is not deleted

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when mongoose doesn't find an element it will still respond back with a 200. Try this website: https://mongoplayground.net/ to test your code.

Before you write your queries for mongoose, always console.log() your req.body to make sure your values are being sent to the server.

```js
const deleteProduct = (productsId) =>{
        axios.post(`/api/product/`,{
            productsId
        })
        .then(response =>{
            setSuccessMessage("Item Deleted Successfully")
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            setErrorMessage(error.response.data.msg)
        })
    }
```

```js
exports.deleteAll = (req, res) => {
const { productsId } = req.body;
console.log(productsId, req.body); //console log your value to make sure
 Product.update({"id": productsId},{$pull: {"id": productsId}}).then(() => {
 res.status(200).json({msg: "Deleted"})
 
 }).catch((err) => {res.status(400).json({msg: "failed"})})
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @user67, mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate isn't too eloquent when it comes to informing whether it has found any document at all and then succeeded in deleting it or if it hasn't found any document and all and, hence, hasn't even tried to delete anything. According to [mongoose's docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete), findByIdAndDelete():

> Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback.

Meaning that checking if the document has been found in the first place is trivial. Just add an extra check before you return the success response:

```
Product.findByIdAndDelete(id , (error, data)=>{
 if(error) {
     console.log('error in deleting')
     throw error;
 }
 if (!data) {
     return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Data not found' });
 }

 console.log('user has been deleted', data);
 return res.status(204).json(data);})
```

Those extra three lines of code seem a little tedious but after some time working with this kind of system I've grown used to adding them because they save me so much time and trouble.